# Wifi not working in Centos 7

Tags: centos, centos7

I recently installed Centos 7 and I have not been able to setup wifi. Whenever I am turning wifi on, I am getting below message :

Below is the output of /var/log/messages

```
Dec  6 22:07:54 [localhost] NetworkManager[4054]: <info>  [1512578274.9743] manager: rfkill: WiFi hardware radio set enabled

Dec  6 22:07:54 [localhost] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled

Dec  6 22:07:54 [localhost] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled

Dec  6 22:07:55 [localhost] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled

Dec  6 22:07:55 [localhost] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled

Dec  6 22:07:55 [localhost] NetworkManager[4054]: <info>  [1512578275.2151] audit: op="radio-control" arg="wireless-enabled:1" pid=2071 uid=1000 result="success"

Dec  6 22:07:55 [localhost] kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp2s0: link is not ready

Dec  6 22:07:55 [localhost] NetworkManager[4054]: <info>  [1512578275.2157] manager: rfkill: WiFi now enabled by radio killswitch

Dec  6 22:07:55 [localhost] google-chrome.desktop: [2559:2665:1206/220755.949908:ERROR:connection_factory_impl.cc(386)] Failed to connect to MCS endpoint with error -106
```

Comment: Since this is not about programming, it is off-topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed the latest version of the driver and it worked.
Strangely driver mentioned that was supposed to be compatible was not good enough